# Monitor doesn't wake up after sleep when connected via DP to a closed-lid MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, external-display, displayport, wake-up

I normally use my MacBook Pro with the lid closed and connected to a external monitor via Thunderbolt (mini-DisplayPort) to DisplayPort cable. The issue I have is that when the Mac is asleep, and I press a key (or multiple) to wake it up, the Mac does wake up (I can hear sounds) but the monitor does not. I've waited for minutes and still doesn't wake up. What I've been doing is pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd> (standby shortcut) twice and then the monitor wakes up. Except for the mentioned issue, everything works perfectly.

What's more, when I work in dual monitor setup (with the lid open), and press any key on the Mac to wake it up, then the monitor DOES wake up as well.

I've already done an SMC reset as instructed [at Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295), although I didn't get any visual indication for whether the procedure worked or not, and the issue is still present.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

**INFO:**

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)
- Graphics Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB
- macOS Mojave 10.14.1 (had the issue with the previous version as well, 10.13.XX)
- Monitor HP Pavilion 32-inch QHD

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't

Comment: I had a similar problem. I ended up sending the monitor for repair, which was covered by warranty. It has been working great since then.

Comment: Huh... I'm still using the same monitor with my new mac and with this new one (M1) it hasn't troubled me. I still have the previous one actually, but changed to using HDMI and it hasn't had that problem that I can remember.